# Преобразование русскоязычной даты в pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть столбец с датами на русском языке типа `str`. Необходимо конвертировать их в тип данных `pandas datetime`. Использовал `pd.to_datetime(errors="coerce")`, но он не сработал. Кварталы трогать необязательно и можно удалить.

| index | Дата |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | IV кв. 2019 г. |
| 5 | I кв. 2020 г. |
| 6 | Декабрь 2009 |
| 7 | Декабрь 2010 |
| 8 | Декабрь 2011 |
| ... | ... |
| 4555 | Февраль 2014 |
| 4556 | Март 2014 |

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос воспроизводимый пример исходных данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала замените русские названия месяцев на их порядковый номер, используя [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) или Series.str.replace

Например:

```
Декабрь —> 01.12
Март -> 01.03
```

После этого воспользуйтесь pd.to_datetime()